# get a different business addresses from api

Tags: ruby

I want to get a different business with a address through api like restaurant, hospital and other services. Is there any api who will provide me this kind of data, Addresses, location, business name, images and other kind of staff. please let me know.

Comment: Google maps API, Foursquare API, Yelp API can do this king of things I think

Answer (score 0):

CityGrid, Fwix, Factual, Facebook Places API